# Bad Address when reading from sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, server, connection, client

i'm facing a problem that i m not able to debug (it seems), let me explain the situation. I have a server that do something and 10 clients to connect. To test the code i use the same machine to host and connect the server and clients. Now, it seems that sometimes i m able to connect a random number of clients, like 4 and during the fifth connection the client side, after a good connection with the server, when i try to read from socket it gives me Bad address.

Now this number seems pretty casual, infact this error on the client side is given sometimes during the third connection, sometimes during the sixth connection and rarely never when i try to connect 10 clients. anyway most of the time this error occurs during the fifth connection.

Here the codes of server and client

Client:

```
void contact_server(int sockfd, int buffer_size, int reading_pipe, int writing_pipe) { 
    float* buff = (float*)calloc(buffer_size,sizeof(float));
    int ret = 0;
    while(1){
        ret = 0;   
        while(ret == 0){
            if(sizeof(float)*buffer_size <= sizeof(float)*2048){
                ret = read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(float)*buffer_size);
                if(ret == -1){
                    printf("(from server) Error description is: %s\n",strerror(errno));
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            else{
                long long unsigned int sum = 0;
                ret = read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(float)*2048);
                if(ret == -1){
                    printf("(from server) Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
                    exit(0);
                }
                sum+=ret;
                int count;
                for(count = 2048; sum < sizeof(float)*buffer_size; count+=2048, sum+=ret){
                    if(buffer_size-count < 2048){
                        ret = read(sockfd, &buff[count], sizeof(float)*(buffer_size-count));
                        if(ret == -1){
                            printf("(from server) Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
                            exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        ret = read(sockfd, &buff[count], sizeof(float)*2048);
                        if(ret == -1){
                            printf("(from server) Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
                            exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }// waiting for server
        ret = write(writing_pipe,buff, sizeof(float)*buffer_size);// writing to parent process
        if(ret == -1){
            printf("(to parent) Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
            exit(0);
        }
        ret = 0;
        while(ret == 0){
            ret = read(reading_pipe, buff, sizeof(float)*buffer_size);
            if(ret == -1){
                printf("(from parent) Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
                exit(0);
            }
        }// waiting for parent process
        ret = write(sockfd,buff, sizeof(float)*buffer_size);// writing to server
        if(ret == -1){
            printf("(to server) Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
            exit(0);
        }
        
    }
    free(buff);
} 


/* See server.c for more specific details
 * 
 * 
 * Inputs:
 *             
 *                 @ int port:= the port of the server
 *                 @ char* server_address:= the server address
 *                 @ int buffer_size:= the buffer size written by the server and parent process
 *                 @ int reading_pipe:= to read from parent
 *                 @ int writing_pipe:= to write to parent
 * */
int run_client(int port, char* server_address, int buffer_size, int reading_pipe, int writing_pipe){
    
    int sockfd, connfd; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;
    int sockaddr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  
    // socket create and varification 
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if (sockfd == -1) { 
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: socket creation failed...\n"); 
        exit(1); 
    } 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
        
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 
  
    // assign IP, PORT 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_address); 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port); 
  
    // connect the client socket to server socket 
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) { 
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("connected to the server..\n");  
  
    // function for chat 
    contact_server(sockfd,buffer_size,reading_pipe,writing_pipe); 
  
    // close the socket 
    close(sockfd);
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Server:

```
void* server_thread(void* _args) {
    
    // depacking args
    thread_args_server* args = (thread_args_server*) _args;
    float* buff = (float*)calloc(args->buffer_size,sizeof(float));
    int ret;
    while(1){
        ret = 0;
        while(ret == 0){
            ret = read(args->reading_pipe, buff, sizeof(float)*args->buffer_size);
            if(ret == -1){
                printf("Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
                exit(0);
            }
        }// waiting for parent process
        ret = write(args->client_desc,buff, sizeof(float)*args->buffer_size);// writing to client
        if(ret == -1){
            printf("Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
            exit(0);
        }
        ret = 0;
        
        while(ret == 0){
            if(sizeof(float)*args->buffer_size <= sizeof(float)*2048){
                ret = read(args->client_desc, buff, sizeof(float)*args->buffer_size);
                if(ret == -1){
                    printf("Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            else{
                long long unsigned int sum = 0;
                ret = read(args->client_desc, buff, sizeof(float)*2048);
                if(ret == -1){
                    printf("Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
                    exit(0);
                }
                sum+=ret;
                long long unsigned int count;
                for(count = 2048;sum < sizeof(float)*args->buffer_size; count+=2048, sum+=ret){
                    if(args->buffer_size-count < 2048){
                        ret = read(args->client_desc, buff, sizeof(float)*(args->buffer_size-count));
                        if(ret == -1){
                            printf("Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
                            exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        ret = read(args->client_desc, buff, sizeof(float)*2048);
                        if(ret == -1){
                            printf("Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
                            exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }// waiting for client
        ret = write(args->writing_pipe,buff, sizeof(float)*args->buffer_size);// writing to parent process
        if(ret == -1){
            printf("Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    free(buff);
    
    return NULL;
}


/* This function creates a server on your current ip address on the port: port,
 * accept a maximum number of connections = max_num_conn, and create each thread per connection.
 * each thread read a float vector from a client and writes on the writing_pipes[i] this vector, then
 * wait for a float vector from reading_pipe[i] and send this vector to the client.
 * The ideal situation is: client -> compute some instances of the mini batch, send to server the partial derivatives
 * the thread of the client on the server side read these partial derivatives, send back to the father process with writing pipes,
 * the parent process sum up all these partial derivatives, update the model, send back to the thread the model updated, the thread
 * send to the client and the client goes on and compute again the new partial derivatives, and so on...
 * 
 * Inputs:
 * 
 *                 @ int port:= the server port
 *                 @ int max_num_conn:= the maximum number of connections accepted by the server
 *                 @ int* reading_pipes:= a pipe writing for float vector to the thread
 *                 @ int* writing_pipes:= where the thread write its vector
 *                 @ int buffer_size:= the buffer of the vector
 * 
 * */
int run_server(int port, int max_num_conn, int* reading_pipes, int* writing_pipes, int buffer_size, char* ip){
    int socket_desc, client_desc,sockaddr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in),c = 1;
    int ret;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in* client_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in* client_addr2;
    
    bzero(&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)); 
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &(&server_addr)->sin_addr);
    // socket creation
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(socket_desc == -1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: can't create socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    // Which connection can accept
    
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    
    // Ip family
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    // Port
    
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    
    // Handling crash case to reuse the descriptor
    
    ret = setsockopt(socket_desc,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&c,sizeof(int));
    if(ret == -1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: setsockopt failed..\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification 
    if ((bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr))) != 0) { 
        printf("socket bind failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n"); 
    
    // listen on tot number of connections
    ret = listen(socket_desc,max_num_conn);
    if(ret == -1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error, listen failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(1){
        client_addr = calloc(1,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        client_desc = accept(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,(socklen_t*)&sockaddr_len);
        if((client_desc == 1 && errno == EINTR)) continue;
        thread_args_server* thread = (thread_args_server*)malloc(sizeof(thread_args_server));
        thread->idx = i;
        thread->client_desc = client_desc;
        thread->client_addr = client_addr;
        thread->reading_pipe = reading_pipes[i];
        thread->writing_pipe = writing_pipes[i];
        thread->buffer_size = buffer_size;
        pthread_t t;
        pthread_create(&t,NULL,server_thread,thread);
        pthread_detach(t);
        printf("connected client id: %d\n",i);
        i++;
    }
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
    
}
```

The error is given by ret = read(sockfd, &buff[count], sizeof(float)*(buffer_size-count)); on client side:
Thank you for the help

Comment: *Where* do you get the error, in the server or the client? And where in the code does it happen? Have you tried to use a debugger to catch the error? Have you used other debugging techniques (like "printf debugging") to check what is going on?

Comment: i get the error on the client side, i catch the error with the ret = -1 when read from server, and errno gives me bad address

Comment: Use network tools such as tcpdump and monitpr all packets transfer between server and clients. Maybe the connection was closed by peer and when client try to read from socket the error is emerged. And also netstat to check the current state of the connection.

Comment: In both the client and server you have `read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(float)*2048)`, which disregards the actual size allocated for `buff` (which in these cases *will* not be enough). The condition `sizeof(float)*buffer_size <= sizeof(float)*2048` is rather odd as well, why not `buffer_size <= 2048`?

Comment: cause i know it can handle 2048*4 or 2048*8 bytes anyway i solved the issued, the problem was that i was incrementing count of 2048, but ret sometimes returned less then 2048*sizeof(float) bytes, so i ve created a char buffer where i store everything and change the storing in &buffer[sum] and only at the end i copy the vector in the float vector buff with memcpy.

Comment: i have only to test when it comes back on server side if i face some other problems i m gonna talk you about it here, if you are available

Comment: That was not the problem cause i check that buffer_size*sizeof(float) is more then 2048 during the first if

Comment: Ah yeah, seems my logic comprehension skills aren't up to snuff today... It's Monday after all. :)

Comment: i feel you ahah

Comment: Still, I suggest you change your logic to clamp the value of `buffer_size` so it won't go over `2048`, before you allocate memory. That will simplify the code quite considerably since then you don't need that check (which you do multiple times) and the extra `read` call. You also have lot of code that is similar or exactly the same, in multiple places. I recommend you move that to a new function to simplify the code even further. And I recommend you try to follow [the single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

Comment: In short: Simpler code is easier to read, understand and maintain. And (which is important for a problem like yours) much easier to debug.

Comment: ok thx for the advice i will do it

Comment: "Bad address" has nothing to do with the networking. It means you passed an invalid memory address to `read`. Double-check that `&buff[count]` is not outside of the space you allocated, and that `(buffer_size-count)` is not a negative number.

Comment: 1) you are not handling partial read()/write() correctly. 2) when read()/write() return -1, you should check errno. It could be EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK, which is not a valid reason to exit.